# My friend's address was spent right after I paid him. What happened?

Tags: theft

Last time I sent some bitcoin to my friend and the fee that I used was a little low, so I tried to broadcast the tx with online broadcasters. After that the tx was spent from my friend's address (not from mine). It showed that my tx confirmed, but as it confirmed another tx was initiated from my friend's address without the permission of him and was spent to another address what kind of attack is it? I think it's not called double spend since it's not spent from my address, it reached his address first but was then spent from him. Can someone explain??

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious, your friend should not trust that wallet anymore and switch away from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read it correctly, your friend had an address, to which you paid. Then someone took it from their wallet?

It might be because your friend's device is hacked or he doesn't use a trustworthy wallet.

Or it was him who spent the coins. It's also possible that they are lying to you so that you pay them again.

Double spend attacks involve the same person spending to two different addresses. Since your friend is not the voluntary author of both transactions, this is not double spend.

I can't comment further without more info.

Comment: I have send the payment to him at 2:00 and my tx was showing me unconfirmed until 3:10 but after it has confirmed my tx shows that it has been confirmed at 2:35 they spend it from his wallet at 2:35 and confirmed their tx at 3:10 which means my tx was showing unconfirmed until they spend from his wallet and confirm their tx i think this will be helpfull to figuer it out